# No selection menu after installing ubuntu with win 10

Tags: system-installation, windows-10

I've just installed latest version of ubuntu along with Windows 10 ... Everything went fine and installation process completed but when I restarted my pc there was no menu to choose whether I want to start windows or linux.. it goes directly to windows 10 ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you disabled Secure Boot in your BIOS?

Comment: Look for a program called boot repair. Boot from live usb stick, install and run the program. It should install / reinstall /fix grub (bootloader that will let you choose an OS at boot.) let me know if you have problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

use live ubuntu cd

---

and install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

---

and fix it by Recommended repair in boot-repair menu

Answer (score 0):

The **correct** answer is to hold down the `LEFT SHIFT` key at boot time, and it'll bring up the `GRUB` menu where you can choose which OS to boot. Cheers, Al